# Possible SELinux-related login issue while running Software Update

Tags: passwords, updates, centos7, selinux

I just performed a clean install of CentOS 7 (*on a laptop*) and the 1st thing I did was to run a software update from the GUI.  A total of 1340 packages were affected, so I just let it do it's thing, and eventually the screensaver kicked-in.  Then a notification window appeared saying "**Sealert Notification**" (*I think it also said* "**1 message**").  I tried to log back in, but it was as though some other process was sending carriage returns to the screen every second (or less), preventing me from typing anything more than a single character at a time, making it impossible to get back to the GUI.

Eventually, my desktop appeared and I was able to regain control of my laptop.  However, this appears to reveal 2 problems:

- What was the application, process, or whatever that was interfering with the GUI log-in screen, preventing me from getting back to my desktop?
- How did my desktop ultimately appear without my entering a password?

I really want to understand how this could have happened, especially the 1st issue, since this is the second system where I've encountered it.

Does anyone have a suggestion where I should look for some clues here?  Is my conclusion that SELinux was somehow connected to the 1st problem (*since it didn't seem to happen until the message box appeared*) correct?